# Volume of Sphere

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm curious about the computation here. The volume of the sphere equation is Volume of Sphere = (4.0/3.0)πr^3. Can anyone explain why for the equation, I can't just put sphereRadius * 3 instead of writing sphereRadius 3 times in a row? I hope this question is clear.

Thanks for the help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SphereVolumeCalculator {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  double piVal = 3.14159;
  double sphereVolume;
  double sphereRadius;

  sphereRadius = scnr.nextInt();

  sphereVolume = (4.0 / 3.0) * piVal * (sphereRadius * sphereRadius * 
  sphereRadius);

  System.out.println(sphereVolume);
   }
}
```

Comment: Mathematically, `r * 3` (`r` times 3) and `r ^ 3` (`r` cubed) are two very different operations.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `sphereRadius * 3` means three times the radius of the sphere.  If instead, you want to take the third power of the sphere, then use `Math#pow`:

```
sphereVolume = (4.0 / 3.0) * piVal * Math.pow(sphereRadius, 3.0d);
```

Note that `Math.pow` technically expects two doubles, so ideally the sphere radius should be a double as well, though the above would also work due to type casting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *cube* the radius, not multiply it by 3. The "*" operator multiplies. Note how it is used to join the elements "(4 / 3)" and "piVal", whose referents in the original formula that we are trying to implement are combined using multiplication (there written simply as juxtaposition, which isn't a very good notation for computer parsing). There is no first-class exponentiation operator in Java, so instead the power is expanded out into self-multiplication with three copies of the exponentiated quantity. In fact, if "*" exponentiated, then the programmed expression would be dramatically, dramatically wrong, perhaps even overflowing horrifically on even small inputs depending on how the association of the operation was set up.

Using "*" to represent multiplication is common parlance in typing environments where that more efficient or elegant notations are not available or might be confusing, such as in simple text messages and in plaintext computer source code files like Java source files. A similar notation, the "x" symbol, is sometimes used as well, however this has the problem that it is literally the letter x, not a separate symbol, and thus is ambiguous with a very commonly-used name for a variable and thus no good as a programming-language operation symbol in many cases.

Moreover, following on this, one might be tempted to think that the "^" operator, used similarly in such writing (as is here, as regrettably Stack Overflow lacks a proper LaTeX- or similar- based mathematics typesetting system though I don't remember the reasons why; you can probably look it up on Meta), but that really refers to a bit-wise XOR in Java. @Tim Biegeleisen suggests you can use Math.pow, however I think it may be that this is less efficient in terms of speed than two multiplications combining three copies of the base. That said, it doesn't matter in this application, but it may in others and thus why that the longhand form is shown instead. Math.pow is really overkill: it is an implementation of what in mathematical terms would be called the *analytic* exponentiation function, which is a transcendental function and typically implemented using a power series or other such rather computationally-intensive process and involves both a transcendental exponential and logarithm operation, as opposed to just three CPU multiplication instructions, which is what the code given will likely JIT compile down to.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SphereVolumeCalculator {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double piVal = 3.14159;
      double sphereVolume;
      double sphereRadius;

      sphereRadius = scnr.nextDouble();

      sphereVolume = (4.0 / 3.0) * piVal * (sphereRadius * sphereRadius * sphereRadius); 
      

      System.out.println(sphereVolume);
   }
}
```